# teleop_twist_joy doesn't publish

Tags: ros, navigation, joystick, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu I have installed the package [ros-indigo-teleop-twist-joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy) in order to convert my joystick input (/joy) to velocity commands (/cmd_vel).

In order to test my setup I ran the provided launch file:

```
$ roslaunch `rospack find teleop_twist_joy`/launch/teleop.launch
```

which appears to run successful.

I can echo the output of /joy, which works as expected:

```
$ rostopic echo /joy
[...]
---
header: 
  seq: 1366
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 310893686
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.13615179061889648, 0.7007878422737122, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1367
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 314848332
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.06840069591999054, 0.7346633672714233, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1368
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 318864098
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0006060103769414127, 0.8137062788009644, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1369
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 322849686
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.8475818634033203, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1370
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 326847977
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.9040411114692688, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1371
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 330820131
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.9830840229988098, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1372
  stamp: 
    secs: 1473747626
    nsecs: 334849495
  frame_id: ''
axes: [0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
---
[...]
```

I can echo the output on /cmd_vel which produces the following ouput everytime I issue the command (and nothing but silence thereafter).

```
$ rostopic echo /cmd_vel
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
```

Looking at the package's default configuration, I would expect to see an effect when I turn the left stick of my gamepad (Logitech F710). Triggering any of the sticks and axes apparantly doesn't change anything.

roswtf and rqt_console are empty. Using rqt_graph I can see that everything is set up correctly (the joy_node is connected to the teleop_twist_node via /joy and the teleop_twist_node is connected to the running echo process via /cmd_vel).

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243560/teleop_twist_joy-doesn%27t-publish/) by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2016-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-09-12**:
Can you post a sample for the msg on /joy topic?

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2016-09-13**:
@DavidN I have posted an extract of the /joy traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you pressing the *enable button*?

The teleop node doesn't send out anything, unless the 'operator' also keeps the enable button depressed. This is analogous to the *deadman* switches found on (industrial) teach pendants fi, and is meant to make it slightly harder for a robot to get out of control by (fi) someone randomly pressing buttons, or if someone lays something on top of the controller.

See the [Parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy#Parameters) section on the `teleop_twist_joy` wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2016-09-13**:
I haven't noticed an influence of any button presses so far either. But I think this may very well be the problem. Does the parameter value of `enable_button` define the index in the button array of the /joy message?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-13**:
Yes. Press and hold down the enable button, while simultaneously moving the joystick. That should result in the appropriate `Twist` messages being published. Whenever you let go of the enable button publication will immediately stop.

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2016-09-13**:
I have now configured the `enable_button` and `enable_turbo_button` to match the indices of the buttons I want to use. Previously they were mapped to indices the joypad didn't address at all. Pressing them now, I get the expected output on /cmd_vel. Thanks for your input!